# ERROR: Property "mainText" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: vue.js, apollo, apollo-client, composition, vue-apollo

I'm using queries Apollo and i want to know how to wait datas to display my page.
Because i'm getting warning and errors. See screen

```
import TemplatePresentationPage from "./../components/TemplatePresentationPage.vue";
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export default {
  apollo: {
    entry: gql`MY QUERY`
  },
  components: { TemplatePresentationPage },
  name: "PresentationRoyalArmy",
  props: {},
  setup() {
    
  },
};
</script>

<template :v-if="entry">

  <TemplatePresentationPage
    :resultOfQuery="entry.datas"
  />
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

[image: errors]

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a solution:

1. Need ton install vue composable (https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide-composable/setup.html)
2. See this page (https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide-composable/query.html#usequery)